# How to get total record count in mongoose schma modal in .pre('save,..) section?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this code, I want to generate school code in shcool_code field like
   SS-000002-S,  SW-000003-S,  TT-000004-S and so one

```
schoolSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var school = this;
    var sName = school.school_name.trim().replace(/\s/g,'').toUpperCase().substring(0,2);
        console.log(school.collection.count);
        school.school_code = sName+'-'+schoolSchema.count+'-S';
        next();
});
```

please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In pre save hook this refer to the document not the model if you want to access the model and get the count use this [middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

```
schoolSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  mongoose.model('modelName').count({}, (err, c) => {
    console.log('count', c);
    next();
  })
});
```

modelName: is the name you registerd your model with.